# Jenkins agent is not honoring hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName

Tags: jenkins

**Background / Environment:**

Jenkins 2.3x on Ubuntu 20.04

I am trying to use a Jenkins Agent installed on the same system as Jenkins server.  Ideally it will connect to just "localhost" when talking to the Jenkins controller.

Jenkins sits behind a reverse proxy which requires 2FA auth (using the [official plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/reverse-proxy-auth-plugin/)).

If a *reason* for me using this local agent is needed, it's because having a standalone agent is a workaround for [this bug](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69061).

---

**Implementation:**

Since the agent can't use the primary Jenkins URL as configured in settings (because that's the proxy URL with 2FA), Jenkins provides the setting `-Dhudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName` to override the main server hostname setting. This is documented [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/).

I've set that value and can confirm that my "custom" name is set when querying the setting:

```
println(System.getProperty("hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName") )
```

Returns:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Which is the local listener of Jenkins and value I expect. I can `curl` and `wget` this address without issue from the host.

---

**The problem**

When starting the agent:

```
java -jar /data/jenkins_home/agent.jar \
  -workDir "/data/jenkins_home/agent_workspace" \
  -failIfWorkDirIsMissing \
  -jnlpUrl http://localhost:8080/computer/local/jenkins-agent.jnlp
```

It tries (and fails) to connect to the **primary Jenkins URL**, ignoring the `hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName` setting

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to <<MY_ACTUAL_JENKINS_URL>>
```

**So, it's **ignoring** the `hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName` value.** This seems to be the primary problem. How can I get it to not use the primary URL value and instead use the URL I give it?

- Everything works fine when the primary Jenkins URL is set directly to the host and not the proxy. However I can't have the agent connect through the proxy since it involves 2FA and is intended for humans to use. I've done several scripts against Jenkins using the direct hostname without issue, this the first time I've had an issue.
- Not using JNLP is an option but it's not well documented and I can't seem to get it going either. [The documentation also states it REQUIRES a secret](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-setup-guide/launch-inbound-agents#_connect_directly_to_tcp_port), and this local agent is meant to connect anonymously.
- I've tried with the agent config setting `Use WebSocket` enabled and disabled. Neither work.
- If I can just tell the agent to use a different URL this whole thing would be solved.

It seems like a simple thing just having an agent connect to a local listener, but apparently I mis-judged the complexity. I'm willing to pretty much configure whatever is needed to get this working so please do shout any ideas!

Comment: tracking this, running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way. I preregister the agents on the jenkins server. This generates in /var/lib/jenkins/nodes/*agent-name*/config.xml file inside that config.xml you can specify the tunnel how it communicates back to the server.
In the config below this is an internal dns (bypassing my proxy). Note also that it uses the Tcp port for the agent connection.

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<slave>
  <name>ubuntu-1</name>
  <description>build node at ubuntu-1 (ip-192-168-xx-yy)</description>
  <remoteFS>/jenkins_workdir</remoteFS>
  <numExecutors>6</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/>
  <launcher class="hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher">
    <tunnel>jenkins-1.cicd-preprod-internal.com:8081</tunnel>
    <workDirSettings>
      <disabled>false</disabled>
       <internalDir>remoting</internalDir>
       <failIfWorkDirIsMissing>false</failIfWorkDirIsMissing>
    </workDirSettings>
    <webSocket>false</webSocket>
  </launcher>
  <label>Ubuntu x86_64 jammy android ubuntu</label>
  <nodeProperties/>
</slave>
```

It is the **tunnel** section on the server that is then passed on via jnlp to the client

This had me puzzled for quite some time as well

Comment: Nice. I can't test it myself because I moved on from this issue (ended up using SSH agents) but I'll mark it as an answer since it seems sane.